# How to get the full path of a dirEntry?

Tags: path, deno, readdir

I want to [`Deno.readDir()`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.readDir) a path and get the full path of each `dirEntry`. The problem is that the [`Deno.DirEntry`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.DirEntry) interface doesn't provide a full path property. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { join } from "$std/path/mod.ts";
const path = "D:\\path\\to\\root"
for await (const dirEntry of Deno.readDir(path)) {
  console.log(join(path, dirEntry.name))
}
```